# Should you combine multiple simple queries into one?

Tags: mysql

Performance wise, is there any reason to combine (using JOIN for example) simple queries like the ones below into one?

media_id and user_id are INDEXES

I can't seem to find an answer and have combined similar queries in the past and ended up with longer overall runtimes.

Edit: I was always told that the fewer queries the better, does that apply here?

```
0.0028      SELECT *
FROM `z_ratings`
WHERE `media_id` = 18610
AND `user_id` = '1' 

0.0013      SELECT *
FROM `z_watchlist`
WHERE `media_id` = 18610
AND `user_id` = '1' 

0.0016      SELECT *
FROM `z_favourite`
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
AND `media_id` = 18610 

0.0021      SELECT *
FROM `z_watched`
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
AND `media_id` = 18610
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? `UNION` ?

Comment: Is the 78ms that those four queries take in aggregate too slow for you?   Remember Knuth's maxim: "***premature optimisation is the root of all evil.***"

Comment: Performancewise is there any merit combining swimming with cooking?

Comment: @eggyal Isn't it '*love of* premature optimisation...' ;-)

Comment: @PM77-1 Would have to be JOIN I think.

Comment: @Strawberry: The full quote is "*Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.*"

Comment: @eggyal There is actually 11 of those. The issue is that I was always told to have as few queries as possible but don't really see the performance issue with having those.

Comment: It simply makes no sense to combine these queries, regardless of any performance benefits. You're asking for four different pieces of information that (as far as we know) have no relationship to one another.

Comment: @Strawberry I think my real question was "is it always better to have fewer queries?" and you answered that so thank you, it will stay as is.

Comment: I don't think I answered that, but anyway...

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your help

Comment: "Fewer queries" only really makes sense as a general rule when the queries used are needlessly numerous (such as when a relatively simple JOIN would prevent a second query from being run repeatedly in a loop based on values from a first query). In most other cases, it greatly depends on circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how exactly you are going to combine them.

If you combine them into one statement using JOIN or UNION, than you need to take indexes into consideration, and check how combined query will fetch the data compare to simple ones.

You may also just concatenate statements into statement block using ";", or to pack them into Stored Procedure. In that case you may actually save time by reducing number of calls to server, but then you may need more complex logic to analyze the result.